# How to ensure that a MySQL slave server is using the SSH tunnel to replicate from the master?

Tags: mysql, ssh, replication

I need to secure MySQL database replication between two CentOS 5.7 servers.  Server 1 has the live database, and replication is already working fine to Server 2 which is located elsewhere on the internet.

Obviously this isn't good as the replication traffic could easily be read, so it needs to be secured.

I created an SSH tunnel by entering this into the Server 2:

```
ssh -f root@server1ip -L 3305:server1ip:3306 -N
```

I confirmed I was able to successfully log into MySQL on Server 1 from Server 2 using:

```
mysql -h27.0.0.1 -uuser -ppassword -P 3305
```

Now, does this mean that the mysql replication is now all going over SSH automatically?  Is there anyway I can confirm this?  Or is Server 2 **forced** to connect to Server 1 over SSH because of this port forwarding rule I have established?

I noticed if I reboot Server 2, the SSH tunnel is gone when it restarts, but the replication continues (I assumed back in plain text).  Is there something I can do make sure the replication stops when the tunnel drops?  I want to make sure it won't automatically continue replicating in clear text without SSH.

Thank you!

Comment: What not use the built-in SSL support?

Comment: I tried for days but could not get it work.  It became very complex when it came to generating and self-signing certificates... this SSH options seems much faster to configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the slave's replication master configuration so that it'll travel over the tunnel's bound port, instead of the external address of the replication peer:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='127.0.0.1' MASTER_PORT=3305;
```

Comment: Thanks Shane! That makes sense now as I can see how the slave will be forced to use the tunnel.  Will this also mean replication will stop (break) if the tunnel drops? Such as a server reboot?

Comment: @dabayl Absolutely!  Take a look at autossh for lighting the tunnel back up when it dies or the server reboots.

Comment: will do. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a SSH-Tunnel i would recommend using [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) which i find easier to manage for non-interactive connection. But that's not a must.

After setting up the conncetion (via SSH or stunnel or something else) you have to start the replication - see Shane Madden's answer. Be sure to use the right MASTER_*-options (see [CHANGE MASTER TO Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/change-master-to.html)).

Also i would prefer to use the build-in SSL-support of mysqld, just as embobo suggested. So you do not have any external dependencies for your replication setup.

All setup mysql should automatic start replication after reboot/restart/... - but be sure to monitor your mysql-replication-setup because there are many situations and circumstances which can break your setup. I really recommend a tool like [pt-heartbeat](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-heartbeat.html) (successor of mk-heartbeat from the maatkit-tools) because `Seconds_Behind_Master` from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G` isn't reliable.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much for the info and links and ideas shared... I'll check them out!  I did try for days to do it with SSL but I couldn't get it work and my understanding of certificates is not very good.  Please let me know if you of any good resources to explain SSL setup. Thanks!

Comment: Good starting points for mysql/SSL are [the mysql docs on SSL in general](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/secure-connections.html) and [the mysql docs on SSL and replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-ssl.html). What exact problems do you have with SSL?